# Printer IP scanning via Nmap

Tags: nmap

I want to scan printer IPs in my organization.  Is there authentic method? I am using Nmap. I have already checked some commands like:

1) `nmap -O 10.10x.x.0/24 -oG - | grep printer >> outfile`
2) `nmap -p 9100,515,631 192.168.1.1/24 -oX printers.xm`

With option 2 I have obtained an xml file, but I don't how to read this file to identify printers because I got many IP's whether they are PCs or printers.

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.x.x
Host is up (0.00082s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
515/tcp  filtered printer
631/tcp  filtered ipp
9100/tcp filtered jetdirect
```

Kindly help me to find out printer IP. I am really messing up. If you want to suggest any command kindly also add some brief instruction for printer IP identification.
One more thing, what is filtered state here?

Answer (score 1):

nmap really isn't designed to do what you're looking for. You would have to know exactly what you are looking for and grep the output for those things, just like you did in your example. But that will only work if the printer responds to pings, and if printers return the results that you expect.

You might be able to eliminate some results by knowing what the OS is on the printers and eliminating results that do not report that OS.

Answer (score 1):

Printers normally use the Sevice Location Protocol to discover and communicate with printers.  You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Location_Protocol), and [here](https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=HPUXSLP).

> The 'Service Location Protocol' (SLP) is an emerging Internet standard network protocol that provides a framework to allow networking applications to discover the existence, location, and configuration of networked services in enterprise networks. This protocol is designed to simplify the discovery and use of network resources such as printers, Web servers, fax machines, video cameras, files systems, backup devices (tape drives), databases, directories, mail servers, calendars.

SLP is not just used for printers, but for many other services.  It is advisable to know what other things on your network use it as well before using it in a pentesting scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Printers usually have SNMP running, so you can use the nmap [SNMP library](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/lib/snmp.html) or just give this a try:

```
 nmap -P0 -v -sU -p 161 -oA snmp_scan 192.168.0.1/24 for i in *.gnmap
 do   for j in $(grep ‘161/open/’ $i | awk ‘{ print $2 }’)   do
     echo $j
     snmpwalk -v2c -c public $j &> snmpwalk_${j}_public.txt
     if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then echo "$j accepts SNMP community string public"; fi
     snmpwalk -v2c -c private $j &> snmpwalk_${j}_private.txt
     if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then echo "$j accepts SNMP community string private"; fi
   done 
 done
```

[Source](https://www.vanstechelman.eu/networking/scanning_for_snmp_services_with_default_community_strings)

This assumes your printers are configured with their default community strings.  If they don't use a public string and you know what it is, go ahead and plug that into the "snmpwalk" portion of the script above.

If you get more than the printers you want, you will have to find a common word in the output (like "printer" as you have used in your post) to grep those results.

Comment: won't this find all nodes that use SNMP?

Comment: That's why the grep is so important.

Comment: According to your code, you will find (grep) all nodes that use SNMP. There doesn't appear to be any way to filter based on printers.

Comment: You'll have to re-read my last sentence, then.

Comment: Then there is no difference from the OP's result from the posted scan. I'm not sure how your code adds anything.

Comment: I think you had to start a newline before the "for" string in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I did it just fine using nmap on Windows, as it collects port fingerprints.

I think you might be able to open nmap xml's with zenmap in order to read it.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. If you have a large list of scanned computers, how do you identify the printer IPs? You're saying that the port fingerprints can help, but how do you turn that into a list?

Comment: You can export the scan results to a csv if possible in linux machines  then create xls table and filter by those fingerprints that show 'printer' or 'jetdirect' or 'ipp'.

A few months back what I did was to parse zenmap xml scan with a powershell script that I found, to convert the xml into a .csv file create an xls table and so on.

See if those might help you if you are still in trouble:
[link1](http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/tip/Creating-an-inventory-with-nmap-network-scanning)

[link2](https://cyber-defense.sans.org/blog/2009/06/11/powershell-script-to-parse-nmap-xml-output)

Comment: You need to edit your answer with these details. If you read the question, the point is being able to filter out the printer IPs from the full scan list in order to run an nmap scan on the printers alone. Your answer, with these other details, amounts to building that list by hand in Excel (or a custom script).